# How to consolidate named exports from multiple files and export as one object

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6, redux

I have a lot of action creators that I am trying to organize into a few different files. Each separate file has exported functions like:

```
export function addData(data) {
  return {
    type: 'ADD_DATA',
    data
  }
}
```

Before they were separated into distinct files, they were imported like:

```
import { addData } from './actions/actionCreators'
```

However with the structure now like

```
├─┬ actions
│ ├── actionsCreators1.js
│ ├── actionsCreators2.js
│ └── index.js
```

I would like to consolidate them in the index file and export them as they were initially named. What I have tried is:

*actions/index.js*

```
import * as actions1 from './actionCreators1'
import * as actions2 from './actionCreators2'

export default {
  ...actions1,
  ...actions2
}
```

However the named functions are undefined when imported. I can bring them in individually `import { action1, action2 } from './actionCreatos1'` and it will work, however it's not ideal to have to write everything in two places.

#### How can consolidate these imports and export them as one object?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rather than relying on spread, you can use the module system itself to pass the names through, e.g.

```
// actions/index.js

export * from './actionCreators1'
export * from './actionCreators2'
```

so as long as the names in the files don't collide, they will just be passed through nicely.

Comment: This is glorious.

Comment: Hi, if I (may) have name collisons, can I group them together to prevent it? For example `export * as One from './actionCreators1'; export * as Two from './actionCreators2' then after importing I can call them like One.addData, Two.addData, is there something like that possible?

Comment: @Zennichimaro Yes, your snippets uses syntax added more recently, but if it fails, you can also do `import * as One from "./actionCreators1"; import * as Two from "./actionCreators2"; export { One, Two };`.

Answer (score 1):

In searching for a consistent export / import pattern, this is one possible solution.

using this for all imports:

`import alpha from './alpha'` (no star)

For the exports:

```
export default {
  ...module.exports,
  ...alpha
}
```

This groups everything with a `export` before it, as well as everything exported from `alpha`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in your *actions/index.js*

```
import * as actions1 from './actionCreators1'
import * as actions2 from './actionCreators2'

export default {
  ...actions1,
  ...actions2
}
```

Since you're exporting as `default`, you would have to import like this:

```
import actions from '../actions'

actions.action1(...)
```

This will **not** work:

```
import { action1 } from '../actions'

actions.action1(...) // Error: action1 is undefined
```

The destructuring syntax can only grab *named* exports, but you're using a *default* export.

I'd like to be able to create named exports with object spread, but alas, it is not valid syntax:

```
import * as actions1 from './actionCreators1'
import * as actions2 from './actionCreators2'

export {
  ...actions1, // object spread cannot be used in an export like this
  ...actions2
}
```

Comment: I thought the default might have been the problem as well. Unfortunately it doesn't look like spread can be used in export like that and `const combinedExports = {
  ...actions1
}

export combinedExports` is a syntax error for some reason.

Comment: Hm, you could always import all of the actions then export them all. There's also a way to export directly from another file (instead of using `import` then `export`): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export